# simple client on golang returns "net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: unexpected EOF"

Tags: go

I use simple client on golang

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    _, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/health")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

and simple http server on python https://gist.github.com/huyng/814831

but I got an error

```
Get "http://localhost:8080/health": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: unexpected EOF
```

What is wrong with my client or server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ...net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: unexpected EOF
> ```
>
> What is wrong with my client or server?

The answer lies in the 6 year old comment immediately below the code you use for the server:

> Nice. A minor HTTP protocol glitch though, as there's no self.end_headers() so the response is malformed when served to picky clients (haproxy). ;)

Thus, don't just take code from somewhere on the internet w/o understanding what it does. Especially, if there is already an explicitly comment saying that the code is broken